# Trying to understand dynamic binding and virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual-functions, dynamic-binding

Given the codes below:

```
class Base
{
public:    
    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "virtual Base::f()\n";
    }
};

class D1 : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void f()
    {
        std::cout << "virtual D1::f()\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    D1 d1;
    Base *bp = &d1;
    bp->f();
    return 0;
}
```

The output was exactly what I had expected:

```
virtual D1::f()
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

But once I removed the `virtual void f()` from `class Base`, the compiler complained that:

```
error: 'class Base' has no member named 'f'
```

Can anyone tell me why compiler didn't generate codes such that it can bind virtual functions at rum time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling virtual member functions via a pointer to `Base`. That means that you can only call methods that exist in the `Base` class. You cannot simply add methods to a type dynamically.

Comment: So..do you mean that it is not allowed to dynamically call any virtual function declared and defined within derived classes but not declared within base class?

Comment: @Alan.W Right, not through a base class pointer anyway. You can try casting to the derived type, then calling the derived functions.

Answer (score 1):

Although a little late as an answer, straight quote from *C++ Primer* on how function calls are resolved in relation to inheritance. ***Your code fails on name lookup (step 2 below), which is done statically.***

> Understanding how function calls are resolved is crucial to
>   understanding inheritance in C++. Given the call p->mem() (or
>   obj.mem()), the following four steps happen:
>
> 1. First determine the static type of p (or obj). Because we’re calling
>      a member, that type must be a class type.
> 2. Look for mem in the class that corresponds to the static type of p (or obj). If mem is not found, look in the direct base class and
>      continue up the chain of classes until mem is found or the last class
>      is searched. If mem is not found in the class or its enclosing base
>      classes, then the call will not compile.
> 3. Once mem is found, do normal type checking (§6.1, p. 203) to see if this call is legal given the definition that was found.
> 4. Assuming the call is legal, the compiler generates code, which varies depending on whether the call is virtual or not:
>
>    – If mem is virtual and the call is made through a reference or
>      pointer, then the compiler generates code to determine at run time
>      which version to run based on the dynamic type of the object.
>
>    – Otherwise, if the function is nonvirtual, or if the call is on an
>      object (not a reference or pointer), the compiler generates a normal
>      function call.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this main function:

```cpp
int main()
{
    D1 d1;
    D1 *bp = &d1;
    bp->f();
    return 0;
}
```

This is because if the `bp` is a `Base` poiter， **Name lookup** will start from the class `Base`